# Outlook 2019 Compatibility with Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, outlook

Is Outlook 2019 supported with Exchange 2010?

The following tables identify the mail clients that are supported for use together with each version of Exchange:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019

Microsoft's official document doesn't mention Outlook 2019 at all. Forums are showing users with Outlook 2019 working with latest version of Exchange 2010 SP3.

I will be retiring Exchange 2010 at the end of the year but in the meantime, I would like to know if Outlook 2019 is supported on Exchange 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my research, it seems no official documents indicates whether Outlook 2019 supports connection to Exchange 2010 or not.
However, I tested with Outlook 2019 (16.0.10730.20102), Exchange 2010 server (14.03.0411.000) in my lab, it worked well.

Here is also [a similar case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/235ebc02-9548-46b5-8afb-c53901e57ed1/does-outlook-2019-work-with-exchange-2010-sp3?forum=outlook) you could refer to.

Comment: https://products.office.com/en-us/office-system-requirements#coreui-contentrichblock-0fnhggf. "Certain advanced functionality may require connectivity to a supported version of Microsoft Exchange Server (or Exchange Online) or Microsoft SharePoint Server (or SharePoint Online). See the Microsoft Support Lifecycle Policy site for supported versions of Exchange Server and SharePoint Server." That statement from Microsoft will work for me.